# Handling multi-variable and multi-station timeseries data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have timeseries data from different stations and each station has a bunch of variables (some same, some different from other stations).  I want to
be able to query by station or variable type, so what would be a good
type of pandas structure to use?

I was thinking of using panels, but it seems that they enforce a
hierarchy.

I would like to be able to so something like  p.temp or p.siteA and
get dataframes back both times

Comment: Why not just add a column that identifies the station also and store all the data in a single df, then you can filter as normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about what you mean by "enforce a hierarchy", but you can accomplish that sort of query with Pandas 3D Panel:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Panel, date_range

index = date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-02-01')
stations = ['Here', 'There', 'Everywhere']
variables = ['temperature', 'salinity', 'oxygen', 'pH']

data = np.empty((len(index), len(stations), len(variables)))
data.shape
(32, 3, 4)

p = Panel(data=data, items=index, major_axis=stations, minor_axis=variables)
p.shape
(32, 3, 4)

p
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 32 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2015-02-01 00:00:00
Major_axis axis: Here to Everywhere
Minor_axis axis: temperature to pH

# Slice by date:
p.ix['2015-01-30']
# by variable
p.minor_xs('salinity')
# by station
p.major_xs('There')
# all together
p.ix['2015-01-30']['temperature']['Here']
```

[This notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/ocefpaf/fa99a226348d157ab90e/raw/4692af119bbc55b1063bcaf8d4009f8cd092ff2e/Panel_demo.ipynb) shows more details on the slices and the resulting DataFrames.